# Unable to switch primary location in demense upon inheritance

Tags: crusader-kings-2

So have a weird situation going on in my ireland game. Have the duchy of leinster and meath, has it so the eldest son inherits everything. I gave all the sons mayoral titles while they wait for dad to drop dead.

So dear old dad finally drops dead. The eldest inherits two duchies, four counties...and the mayoral title. The problem is it keeps complaining that the county that the town is in, is the wrong type to have demense wise. Cant' give away the mayoral title, nor switch the castle and town for being primary location in that county. Best part is now it says that instead of my son that would inherit, it's the chancellor that isn't even connected to my family tree at all.

So is my game buggered, or is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the holding and convert to vassal. Your character isn't technically allowed to 'run' a city or a church. (S)He may only run Baronies as they are literally in the royalty hierarchy.

Why is this? Cities want to elect their own Mayor so the townfolk would prefer a mayor to a King. The church thing is a bit more complicated but until you become a King, you have free reign over who succeeds as a given church's bishop but once a character controls the holding the usual problems for removing a title crop up.

A second note on the Bishop problem, if future readers are curious, is that once your main character becomes a King (s)he has the issue of crown laws and the subsequent issue of free or Papal investiture. You'll have to look more into the consequences of either choice but the relevant issue is that under Papal investiture your King has no influence over Bishop appointments.